# Trying to connect String to login SQL datebase

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, authentication

```
if (txtUserName.Text != "" & txtPassword.Text != "")
{        
    string queryText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Login_N_Password " +
                               "WHERE username = @Username AND Password = @Password";
    string _connectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Team Project\Cohort1_T5\DatabaseRoster\MSSADatabase;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MSSADatabase_log.ldf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))

    // MSSADatabase_log.ldf
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, cn))
    {
         cn.Open();
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);  // cmd is SqlCommand 
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

         int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

         if (result > 0)
             MessageBox.Show("Loggen In!");
         else
             MessageBox.Show("User Not Found!");
    }
}
```

I am new to this site. I have to make a login connection and form for a roster. However I don't know how to use connection strings help please.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What doesn't work? P.S. [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: your connection string seems odd you can not connect to the .mdf file directy just browse the web for Connection string example

Comment: ***Please*** do tell me you're **not really** storing passwords in **clear text** in your database ......

Comment: You should put your connection string in your config file instead of coding it on every page. And storing password in clear text...

Comment: The is just beginner problem for an in house project. Basically I am self learning starting here. then ill move up to more advance password storing later.   the error is "Additional information: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'."

Answer (score 0):

for your _connectionString I don't think you need the @ in front of the string. All of the connection strings I have set up did not include that. Otherwise, using a ConnectionString builder might help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The @ in there is the delimit all backslashes in a string in c#. The ampersand is not in the value of the string. You could also go into the values and double up every backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Another generally useful resource is http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for this and similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the connection string is not right.

We use "Data Source" to initialize the server name.

The format to right connection string can be:

```
string conStr = "Data Source = (your_server_name); Initial Catalog = your_database_name; Integrated Security = true;"
```

May be you are looking for this.